# 'module' object has no attribute 'openSPI' on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, rfid

I'm trying to use the rPi SPI (read from RFID-RC522) port using [this repo](https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git).

When I'm trying to run `test-nRF.py` on a Raspberry Pi, I'm getting the following error:

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~/SPI-Py $ python test-nRF.py install Traceback (most
 recent call last):   File "test-nRF.py", line 11, in <module>
     status = spi.openSPI(speed=1000000) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openSPI'
```

I installed the MFRC522-python library and the SPI-Py also but I got the same error.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same Problem... You got to use [virtual-env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (recommended by community).

Did you import SPI in your script?

Else:

Reinstalling all the dependencies inlcuding the SPI Module in an active virtual-environment did the trick for me.

The Doc´s: [Virtualenv.](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)